# Powershell passing array to other script, turns to system hastable? Fix?

Tags: arrays, powershell, parameter-passing

In Powershell I am attempting to pass an array as an argument to a second script, however this, according to the debugger, is managed by the second script as a system.collection.hashtable object. How can I fix this?

**calling script code**

```
$images = @{ 
   image1 = "$dir\welcomeMessageAtaP1_files\image001.jpg" 
}  
..\sendmail.ps1 –subject $subject1 –body $fixed3 -recipient $personalemail -images $images
```

**sendmail.ps1 code**

```
 param (
    [string]$subject = "** EMPTY **",
    [string]$body = "** EMPTY **",
    [string]$recipient = "email@somedomain",
    [string[]] $images=@()
 )
$params = @{ 
    InlineAttachments = $images 
    Body = $body 
    BodyAsHtml = $true 
    Subject = $subject 
    From = "emailsender@somedomain"
    To = $recipient 
    SmtpServer = 'smtp.gmail.com' 
    Port = 587 
    UseSsl = $true 
} 

Send-MailMessage @params -Credential $cred
```

Throws the error "Send-MailMessage : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'InlineAttachments'. Cannot convert the "System.String[]" value of type "System.String[]" to type "System.Collections.Hashtable".

Tried also to change param to `[string] $images=@()`

Comment: You define `$images` as a *hashtable*, but your script expects a *string array* for the parameter `-images`. What did you expect would happen?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, isn't the called script expecting a hashtable, when using  `[string[]] $images=@()` ??

Comment: Why would it? `@()` is the array subexpression operator, which gives you an empty array, and `[string[]]` forces the type of your parameter to "string array" anyway.

Comment: So how do I pass a hashtable from one script to another one? Is this correct? `[string]$images = @{}`

Comment: You still don't understand. `[Type]$ParameterName` in a parameter block defines a parameter of a specific ***type***. Do `hashtable` and `string` look like they're the same type to you?

Comment: Got it to work. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You indeed pass a Hashtable. `@{}` does create a Hashtable and you have a Key `Image1` and a value `"$dir\welcomeMessageAtaP1_files\image001.jpg"`

```
$images = @{ 
   image1 = "$dir\welcomeMessageAtaP1_files\image001.jpg" 
}
```

instead pass an array `@()`:

```
$images = @( 
       "$dir\welcomeMessageAtaP1_files\image001.jpg" 
    )
```